# ABAP Dynpro Flow logic - Find field (name) after POV call

Tags: abap, dynpro

I would like to know if you know a way to find the name of a field after calling a POV.
For example,

A dynpro with this code (Flow logic) :

```
process on value-request.
  field _field_ module dynpro_pov.
```

An ABAP program where the module is defined

```
MODULE dynpro_pov INPUT.
  " How can I get the name of the field "_field_" here ?
ENDMODULE.
```

**Do you know of a way to find the name _*field_* dynamically in ABAP code ?**

*I thought of having a buffer variable which store the value in the dynpro flow logic and retrieve the value in the ABAP code but obviously we cannot write such an ABAP instruction.
And then I might have thought that a DYNP * type FM would do the trick with the correct CALL ID. But I didn't find anything.*

Thanks

Comment: This sounds a lot like an XY problem. Why would you have the same but different value help for different fields?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the statement [`GET CURSOR`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget_cursor_dynpro.htm) to retrieve the field that is currently selected by the user (which is equivalent to the field the user requests the value help on):

```
DATA field TYPE string.
GET CURSOR FIELD field.
```